# mysql avoiding subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table with three columns

```
userid,eventid,entrytime
```

and values like

`userid,eventid,entrytime
  1      1      NULL
  2      1    2012-01-01
  1      2    2012-01-01
  2      2    2012-01-01
  3      1      NULL
  3      2      NULL`

What is the best way of selecting userids where entrytime has always been NULL

Comment: Wow, a big stack of answers where the question was not thoroughly read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a `COUNT(entrytime)` aggregate will eliminate NULL values, you can use it to determine which `userid` has no non-null value for `entrytime` by comparing it to 0 in the `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(entrytime)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY userid
HAVING COUNT(entrytime) = 0
```

[Here is a live demonstration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4a4a/1) (Result is `userid` = 3)

Comment: @bobwienholt I hope that hasn't been your experience.  There are [some really bright people](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/topusers) in the MySQL and SQL tag categories.

Comment: +1 Ahh.. this is better than mine... i didn't think about COUNT(entrytime) :(

Comment: This works fine 
Is there a way of optimizing this. Assume the table has 20 million records then this query takes 25 minutes I have a index on userid+eventid. And using MyISAM tables the table also stands locked

I think fetching records one by one in a perl script would be a better choice

Comment: @Ram If you mean to say there is a composite index across `(userid,entrytime)` it may benefit from a single index on `entrytime`. Hard to say without seeing the `EXPLAIN`

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
select userid from
(select userid,entrytime,count(*) from yourtable 
group by userid,entrytime)a
group by userid
having count(*)=1 and max(entrytime) is null
```

## [SQl Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4a4a/9)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.UserId
FROM <TableName> t1
    LEFT JOIN <TableName> t2 ON t1.UserID = t2.UserID AND t2.EntryTime IS NOT NULL
WHERE t2.UserID IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    select userid from table_name  where entrytime is null
```

Comment: _where entrytime has **always** been NULL_

Comment: s, this query will return userid where entry time is always null

Comment: it will return _rows_ where `entrytime IS NULL`. It won't return `userid` for whom _all_ `entrytime` are NULL.

Comment: in the same your demo kindly check this query

Comment: [like this??](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4a4a/3) It returns userid=1, which _has_ a non-null entrytime in the third sample row.